# You can make me sink, yet I have no weight. / You can make me wave, but you might regret

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

You can make me sink, yet I have no weight.
You can make me wave, but you might regret.
Give me a bird, and I become a non-believer.
Give me to a sea, and I won't help you prosper.
**What am I?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are:

> **HEAT**

*You can make me sink, yet I have no weight.*

> [Heat sink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_sink) - heat itself has 'no weight'.

*You can make me wave, but you might regret.*

> [Heat wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_wave) - it'll get HOT!

*Give me a bird, and I become a non-believer.*

> HEAT + HEN (a bird) = HEATHEN (a non-believer)

*Give me to a sea, and I won't help you prosper.*

> C ("sea") + HEAT = CHEAT (and cheaters never prosper!)

Comment: And now with summer, coming out of its shell / I sure hope the [word], is treating you well

Comment: @Auribouros It's really not! (wipes brow)

Comment: And there's me in the opposite right now...

Comment: "a relatively light computer component." It is often the heaviest computer component, short of the case...

Comment: @Aron I meant more 'relative to other things in life' rather than specifically  to other computer components... I was trying to interpret 'no weight' as 'not very much weight, all things considered...'

Comment: @Stiv My Noctua NH-D15 weighs over 1kg. That isn't a feather to the face if you get my drift. Heatsinks are literally a block of metal.

Comment: The original point the riddle was trying to get across is that heat itself doesn't have much weight, not the heatsink.

Comment: @Auribouros And that makes a LOT more sense - will amend my answer appropriately! (Totally forgot the pronoun going on there...)